# Incorrect Integer value: 'undefined' for column 'user_id'

Tags: mysql, reactjs, fetch, undefined, react-props

I am a bit confused here as I'm trying to submit a post, however, it gives me `'user_id' 'undefined`, but if I console.log I see that the integer is 12. I've been trying many different things in the last two days, without success and I am not able to see the problem here (please, bear in mind that I am a beginner in coding).

This is the route:

```
routes.post("/profile/share", (req, res) => {
    let { user_id, body, createdAt, updatedAt } = req.body;
    
    db(`INSERT INTO shares (user_id, body, createdAt, updatedAt) 
        VALUES ('${user_id}', '${body}', '${createdAt}', '${updatedAt}'); 
        `)
        .then(results => {
            if(!results.error) {
                res.status(201).send({})
            }
            res.send(results)
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(500).send(err))
})
```

This is the function in my component:

```
handleSubmit = event => {
      event.preventDefault()
      const { user_id } = this.props.user[0].id
      console.log(this.props.user[0].id)
      const { body, createdAt, updatedAt } = this.state
          axios.post("http://localhost:7001/api/profile/share", {
            data: {
              user_id,
              body,
              createdAt,
              updatedAt
            }
          }) 
          .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data)
            this.setState(state => ({
              loggedIn: !state.loggedIn,
            }))
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
          })
    }
```

This is the console:
[image]

And the message from error 500:

[image]

Does anyone spot where my error is? Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What database library are you using? I think your program is vulnerable to SQL injection (I know some modern JavaScript libraries safely handle template-strings and parameters, but I'm unsure in your case).

Comment: Do you have a debugger for your NodeJS code?

Comment: @Dai no, I don't have it. I'll research now about it and try to implement it.

Comment: https://www.moesif.com/blog/technical/debugging/debugging-nodejs-api-with-vscode/

Comment: I think this is the issue -  const { user_id } = this.props.user[0].id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the console log  `this.props.user[0].id` is a number. You shouldn't destructure it, instead, you can directly assign it to a variable and use it.

As you are destructuring, the `user_id` is going as undefined that is causing the issue.

```
const { user_id } = this.props.user[0].id;  This should be change to

const user_id = this.props.user[0].id;
```

Pass the params like below:-

```
axios.post("http://localhost:7001/api/profile/share", {
              user_id,
              body,
              createdAt,
              updatedAt
          })
```

Comment: Thank you @UKS, I've tried but it gives me the same error

Comment: Did you check the post request? All the values are setting properly?

Comment: Yes, the post request in Imsomnia is working properly, adding the id manually.

Comment: One more thing you can try is, remove `data ` in the axios.post. Pass flat object.     Reference -https://flaviocopes.com/node-axios/

Comment: It does not work either. I wanna cry! In the request payload the data appears correctly, so I don't understand why is this happening.